# Getting Invalid application ID error when using Test application ID with adMob

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am getting an error when i am trying to implement admob to my app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:Invalid application ID
```

I am using test application ID. Here is my manifest:

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
```

Activity code

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML code

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
```

I do not understand why i am still getting Invalid application ID code. I am using test application ID

Comment: You have to put real application id in the manifest and use the test id in adview

Answer (score 9):

You put your Ad Unit ID in AndroidManifest.xml - which is wrong. You should add your **AdMob App ID** here.

**Ad Unit IDs** have this format:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111  //Test ID for a banner
```

**AdMob App IDs** have this format:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713  //Test App ID
```

Comment: Thanks man, and it is better to say how to find it. (App setting -> App ID).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems that in manifest i have to put real application ID

Comment: That is not right. You can and should use the test app_id ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 here as well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a real ID in both the cases, i.e., the app ID case and also the AdUnit case. If you are in testing, then you may use test ones. But on release, use real IDs from your AdMob dashboard to get real ads when users use your app. Otherwise, the ads won't work.